# Jira reload gadget specification cache

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We have a custom jira gadget that summarizes the time developers booked on tickets.

When I make a change to the specification file (gadget.xml), there doesn't seem to be any way to know when the change will be reflected on the users' browser.  Jira appears to cache the specification.

Is there any way to force the refresh of this content, without all users having to re-add the gadget to their dashboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart JIRA.  During development, markdemich`s method is best for quick tests but for clearing cache across JIRA, a simple restart clears the cache for all gadget instances.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you add `?ignoreCache=true` to you url

```
http://<your host>/Dashboard.jspa?ignoreCache=true
```

should do it.

Comment: But then that means that every user needs to know when to use that url? I suppose using it all of the time will slow down Jira?